# Second command on docker-compose is not executed

Tags: python, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file. and in the command part, i have 2 commands. The first one is for upgrading the pip3 and the second one to install requeriment of the python project.

```
version: '3'

services:
  remote_interpreter :
    image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01
    entrypoint: ""
    command: "pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r ./tests/requirements.txt"
```

However, when i run the `docker-compose -f ./my-file.yaml up` , i don't see the packages inside the requirements.txt are being installed.

Also, how i can keep the container which is built on based this docker-compose file running, so that i can check if the needed packages are really installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your commands in a single shell. Try this:

```
command: sh -c "pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r ./tests/requirements.txt"
```

More info at https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-compose-multiple-commands